# SQL count occurance of numbers in a list based on range condition

Tags: sql, count, conditional-statements, range

I need to create two columns *Flag1* and *Flag2* that contain counts based on the range condition:
If PostCode is in the range 000-500 then *Flag1* else *Flag2*.

**Raw data**

| RowdID | PostCode |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 301AD, 478GH, 921SS, 810RT, 019FE |
| 2 | 296KS, 035LC, 592MW |

**Output**

| RowdID | PostCode | Flag1 | Flag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 301AD, 478GH, 921SS, 810RT, 019FE | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 296KS, 035LC, 592MW | 2 | 1 |

Comment: This is what you are looking after "SQL Case When Statement" : https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making a few assumptions here:

1. That the postcode column does not contain special characters. If it does, then adjust the regexp_replace expression.
2. That you only care about postcode values with numbers.
3. You don't have postcodes with nnnAAAnn format (like 012ABC24). If you do, then use a substring of (split-to-table, 1, 3) rather than regexp_replace function.

Also, I'm writing this in postgres. You didn't specify a dbms, so adjust as needed.

This part of the query takes your wide table and generates a tall "table".

```
select id, 
cast(regexp_replace(regexp_split_to_table(postcode, ','), '[[:alpha:]]', '','g') as integer) as postcode_digits
from table1
```

Parts of that query:

```
regexp_split_to_table --> creates a tall table of your comma separated data in the postcode column. 

regexp_replace(tall table, '[[:alpha:]]', '','g'  ) --> this replaces letters with nothing, so that we're keeping only the numbers. 

cast(inner output) to integer --> so 456 is 456 as integer, and 012 becomes 12.
```

What that looks like:

| id | postcode_digits |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 301 |
| 1 | 478 |
| 1 | 921 |
| 1 | 810 |
| 1 | 19 |
| 2 | 296 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 2 | 592 |

Given that knowledge, here is the entire query:

```
select t.id, t.postcode, 
sum(case when postcode_digits <= 500 then 1 else 0 end) flag1, 
sum(case when postcode_digits > 500 then 1 else 0 end) flag2
from (
    select id, 
    cast(regexp_replace(regexp_split_to_table(postcode, ','), '[[:alpha:]]', '','g') as integer) as postcode_digits
    from table1)z
join table1 t
  on z.id = t.id
group by t.id, t.postcode
```

Output:

| id | postcode | flag1 | flag2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 301AD, 478GH, 921SS, 810RT, 019FE | 3 | 2 |
| 2 | 296KS, 035LC, 592MW | 2 | 1 |

DB-fiddle found [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2MawLvPgyeS1bu6FCesgL2/0).

Comment: Thank you so much, @Isolated for sharing the general approach as well as the Postgres code. I should have mentioned MS SQL server environment, but it was a good practice to find parallels in sql server dbms based on your suggestion. Also,
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) came in handy.
`SELECT Id, postcode, SUM(CASE WHEN (LEFT(value,3) <= 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) flag1, SUM(CASE WHEN (LEFT(value,3) > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) flag2
FROM table1 CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(postcode, ',') GROUP BY [Id]`